# Global Service to Define Global Variables in Angular 6

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I have searched a lot for defining global variables in angular but not found anything related to my issues. I have global configuration file for complete project which is in json format at secured place and my express app can access it and provide required details on respective API calls.

For almost every component of my app few configuration parameters(Which will come through API) are required before Init.
So currently i am calling the same API via multiple components, instead of it i want to use angular service to access global(s). But sometimes API takes time to respond and component is not waiting for the service to respond.

So is there any way to call API once (for e.g. in app.module.ts) and store the response object locally (for e.g. global variables, session storage) and make it available for every component so that they  will not required to call API and wait for the response before they load.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are several articles that detail approaches to doing this (there is more than one way to do this). Search on keywords `angular how to runtime configuration` and start researching. If you get stuck with a specific approach come back and ask a question with the details. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this, its actually very easy - you can use behaviorsubject or subject.  create a service, and you can store the values and call them as object observables throughout all of your app - you can also make them async and use away on the function or the better approach is to turn the response into a promise.

**service**

```
private yoursubject = new Subject()
public yoursubject$ = this.yousubject.asobservable()

async yourfuntion(yoursubject: any): any {
private yourgeturl = 'http://yoururl.com/apikey'
this.httpClient.get(yourgeturl).toPromise().then((result)=>{
result = await result
this.yoursubject.next(result)
}
```

**import into component you want and subscribe to it or use it as a promise**

```
constructor(private yourservice: YourServiceName) {}
yourvariable ?: string;
this.yourservice.subscribe((yourdatename)=>{
yourdataname = yourdataname,
this.yourvariable = yourdataname })
```